# Map JSON response from Ruby to Python

Tags: python, json, ruby, python-3.x, code-conversion

**[EDIT]: Sorry I didn't explain in enough details the first time as I kind of wanted to figure the rest out for myself, but I ended up confusing myself even more**

I have a small problem. 
I wanted to take advantage of a website's API JSON response

```
{
    "Class": {
        "Id": 1948237,
        "family": "nature",
        "Timestamp": 941439
    },
    "Subtitles":    [
      {
        "Id":151398,
        "Content":"Tree",
        "Language":"en"
      },
      {
        "Id":151399,
        "Content":"Bush,
        "Language":"en"
      }
    ]
}
```

So I'd like to print the url with a combined string of each line of subtitles, seperated by newlines

And I manage to do so in Ruby like this:

```
def get_word
    r = HTTParty.get('https://example.com/api/new')
# Check if the request had a valid response.
    if r.code == 200
        json = r.parsed_response
        # Extract the family and timestamp from the API response.
        _, family, timestamp = json["Class"].values

        # Build a proper URL
        image_url = "https://example.com/image/" + family + "/" + timestamp.to_s

        # Combine each line of subtitles into one string, seperated by newlines.
        word = json["Subtitles"].map{|subtitle| subtitle["Content"]}.join("\n")

        return image_url, word
    end
end
```

However now I need to port this to python and because I'm terrible at python I can't really seem to figure it out.

I'm using requests instead of HTTParty as I think it's the best equivalent.
I tried doing this:

```
def get_word():
  r = requests.request('GET', 'https://example.com/api/new')
  if r.status_code == 200:
      json = requests.Response
      # [DOESN'T WORK] Extract the family and timestamp from the API response. 
      _, family, timestamp = json["Class"].values

      # Build a proper URL
      image_url = "https://example.com/image/" + family + "/" + timestamp.to_s

      # Combine each line of subtitles into one string, seperated by newlines.
      word = "\n".join(subtitle["Content"] for subtitle in json["Subtitles"])
      print (image_url + '\n' + word)

get_word()
```

However I get stuck at extracting the JSON response and combining the lines

Comment: Can you give an example of what that would look like from the data set you provided for those who don't know Ruby?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain enough, I kind of wanted to figure the rest out for myself but I ended up confusing myself even more.
The desired output is by example:

`https://example.com/image/nature/941439  Tree  
bush`
Of course there won't always be only two subtitles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to convert the incoming json to python dictionary

Assuming this is your response

> response = {"Subtitles":   ...}

```
#convert to dict
import json
json_data = json.loads(response)
# print content
for a_subtitle in response['Subtitles']:
    print(a_subtitle['content'])

# extract family and timestamp
family = json_data["Class"]["family"]
timestamp = json_data["Class"]["Timestamp"]
image_url = "https://example.com/image/" + family + "/" + str(timestamp)
```

Comment: That's interesting and I thank you for your help, however another of my problem is that I don't know how I could convert the ruby code:
`json = r.parsed_response  
 _, family, timestamp = json["Class"].values`
to Python

Comment: You will again parse the json_data.
`family = json_data["Class"]["family"]`
`timestamp = json_data["Class"]["Timestamp"]`

Answer (score 2):

The Pythonic way is to use a list comprehension.

```
Word = "\n".join(subtitle["Content"] for subtitle in json["Subtitles"])
```